# Chaining in Javascript without setting state

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

I like jQuery's ability to method chain commands ( .animate().css() etc ) which in the backend is achieved by returning the special variable "this".

How can I implement a similar method of chaining without having to set state within my object. Take for example:

```
that.getHospitalCoverDataStore().findBy('short_name').withValue('sam');
```

This method chain queries a field in the datastore "short_name" using the value "sam". I can set an internal state to "short_name" when the first method has been called then look that up again when withValue is called. This seems like a kludge to me though, for a start I can't throw an error if withValue is called before findBy as it will reuse the last findBy setting.

How can I better implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `findBy` method return a different object, that encapsulates the datastore and the field name, and that has the `withValue` method:

```
function findBy(field) {
  return {
    dataStore: this,
    field: field,
    withValue: function(value) {
      // query the dataStore and return result
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Love it, this is what I was thinking so it's good to get some confirmation on it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `findBy` method should return a separate object with a `withValue` method. (and perhaps `startsWith`, but no unrelated methods)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `findBy()` could be implemented as a separate object with the method `withValue()`, it doesn't look like `withValue()` should be a method for the HospitalCoverDataStore.